# How to set PYTHONPATH in OS X to use PyQGIS?

Tags: python, pyqgis

I am trying to use PyQGIS in custom applications.

I am on Mac OS X 10.9 with QGIS 2.0.1-Dufour.

I know I have to set the the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

This is the path to QGIS on OS X: `/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/`

My current `PYTHONPATH` is the following:

```
$ echo PYTHONPATH
PYTHONPATH
```

Next I tried to export the QGIS Python path:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python
-bash: $: command not found
```

Then I tried it with `sudo`:

```
$ sudo -s export PYTHONPATH=/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python
```

This worked. But when I check my `PYTHONPATH` again it is the same as before:

```
$ echo PYTHONPATH
PYTHONPATH
```

What steps am I missing in order to set the `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: Are you doing this in the terminal?

Comment: Yes, I do this in terminal. Is that the wrong place?

Comment: should be `echo $PYTHON_PATH`

Comment: If it's failing on the `export` command without sudo something might be messed up in your bash setup.

Comment: `echo $PYTHON_PATH`returns an empty line.

Comment: Sorry I mean `$PYTHONPATH`

Comment: Also `echo $PYTHONPATH` returns an empty line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand your problem:

in BASH:

```
$ STR='hello'
$ echo STR
STR
$ echo $STR
hello
```

Basically, $ is used when referring to a variable, but not when defining it. For BASH STR = STR and $STR refers to the variable STR:

```
$ $STR='hello'
-bash: hello=hello: command not found
```

So, in your case, as [Nathan W](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/97/nathan-w) says:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python
$ echo PYTHONPATH
PYTHONPATH
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python
```

And if you want to use another path to PYTHONPATH:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mapnik.framework/Python:$PYTHONPATH
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/Library/Frameworks/Mapnik.framework/Python:/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python
```

or you can set the order of importation:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Library/Frameworks/Mapnik.framework/Python
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python:/Library/Frameworks/Mapnik.framework/Python
```

And if it's failing without sudo, your have a problem with your Mac OS X permissions.

Comment: That worked. I wasn't aware of the significance of the `$` sign. Thanks for making that clear!